# Re-provisioning without losing data

Tags: .net, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

There's any way to re-provision a local database without losing the local data, (using Sync framework 2.1) ?

My scenario is:

1. Add a new column on Remote DB
2. Re-provisioning the Remote DB (to include the new column on the synchronization template)
3. Re-provisioning the LOCAL DB.

My problems start at step 3 because I need to drop all the tables present on LOCAL DB to be able to get the new scope, otherwise I will get the Exception: `"Invalid column name 'new column'"`

So, it is possible to re-provision a local DB without drop the older tables ?

Please, all the help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

deprovisioning doesnt remove data, it only removes metadata/objects associated associated with a scope. If its database deprovisioning, it removes all Sync Fx created objects.

so the good side, you don't lose data.
the bad side, if you reprovision a new scope on the same table, they already have data. But new scope doesnt know about these data (the sync knowledge is empty on new scopes) so you end up synching existing rows which in turn results to conflicts.

wiping one of the replicas is the quickest solution.

Comment: my scenario is:
If i add a new Column on Remote Db i need to set a new scope to include that Column.
And when i get that new Scope on Local DBs it throws a exception because the new column is unknown.
So, to add that new Scope i need to drop the older tables in Local DB acording to get the new ones (that include the new Column), am i right ?

Comment: My comment is well explained ?
I mean, if a add a new table column to a remote Scope and get that Scope from a local Db, i will run into exceptions because the new column is unknown in Local DB

Comment: You have to add the column to the tables yourself. Adding the new column to a new column only tells Sync Fx to include it in the sync scope definition. Sync Fx will not alter your table to add the column.

Comment: Thanks JuneT it works fine, you already save my life a couple of times :)
But now i run it to another question (that you mention above), so
when i reprovision i loose all the sync knowledge but there's any way to keep or restore the tracking tables with the information of syncked regists ? I've been tried to restore the tracking tables information using SqlSyncStoreRestore but it stores the information indicating that all regist are not syncked

Comment: the sync knowledge is not on the tracking tables. the tracking tables simply records what has changed. sync knowledge is in the scope info table. and no, you cannot restore this information from one scope to another.

Comment: So i have no other option than re-synch all the data when i re-provision the databases, right ?

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to drop the databases.   de provision both databases. And add new columns for data table and run the sync. This should work.  This is how you deprovison.

```
   SqlSyncScopeDeprovisioning scopeDeprovisioning = new SqlSyncScopeDeprovisioning((SqlConnection)_peerProvider.Connection);
            scopeDeprovisioning.ObjectSchema = _dbProvider.ObjectSchema;
            // Remove the scope.
            scopeDeprovisioning.DeprovisionScope(this._peerProvider.ScopeName);
```

Comment: Right, but after doing that deprovision, i new to provision a new scope that contains new elements (such as columns and tables), and the problem is in there. If i add a scope that have some new tables and columns the provisioning is not allowed